# How to get a line using a pattern before a line number?

Tags: unix, sed

I need to get a line which matches a pattern before a certain line number of a file.

Example:

```
linenum 1.fruits
linenum 2.cherry
linenum 3.apple
.
.
linenum 7.orange
linenum 8.apple2
.
.
.
linenum 20.strawberry
```

From the above file, I want line8. I know it will come above line 20, and I know that line contains `apple`.

Comment: What to you want to do with line8? What have you tried. Most questions can be answered [here](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/sed.html).

Comment: What criteria (aside from "_it has `apple`_") are you working with? Just any line above line 20 that has `apple`?

Comment: Please add some context and show your efforts, otherwise this looks like an exercise to learn `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `sed`:

```
sed -n '20,$d;/apple/h;19{x;p}'
```

- `-n` - suppress printing of lines
- `20,$d` - for any line from `20` to the end of the file (`$`), delete (`d`) it
- `/apple/h` - for any line that matches the regex `/apple/`, copy any it to the "*hold space*" (`h`)
- `19{x;p}` - on line `19`, swap the pattern and hold spaces (`x`) and print the pattern space (`p`)

Note that it's necessary to use line `19` for the final print, because all lines after this are deleted. Otherwise you could use the "*last line*" address - `$`.

---

In this test, I have added an `apple` to line 23.

```
$ sed -n '20,$d;/apple/h;19{x;p}' < file
linenum 8.apple2
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite the tag is [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), my answer doesn't use `sed`.

The following command takes first 19 lines, discards ones without `apple`, then returns the last line from what's left:

```
head -n 19 | grep "apple" | tail -n 1
```

To process a file named `file.txt`:

```
<file.txt head -n 19 | grep "apple" | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Same solution as already posted, this time in Perl:

```
perl -lane 'if(1..19 and /apple/){$a=$_} END{print $a}' input.txt
```

and AWK:

```
awk 'NR<20 && /apple/ {a=$0} END{print a}' input.txt
```